# A question on measurable space and $\sigma$-algebra generated by a familly of subsets

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(E, \mathbb M)$ be a measurable space and $\mathbb C$ be a familly of subsets of $E$. Show that, for every $B \in \sigma(\mathbb C)$, there exists a countable familly $\mathbb D \subset \mathbb C$ such that $B \in \sigma(\mathbb D)$. ($\sigma(X)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$)

Denote $\mathbb G = \{ B \in \sigma(\mathbb C)$ such that there exists a countable familly $\mathbb D \subset \mathbb C$ satisfies $B \in \sigma(\mathbb D) \}$.

We can show that $\mathbb G$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $E$. Now I have $2$ questions:

1. Why does this imply $\mathbb G = \sigma(\mathbb C)$? (We have $\mathbb G \subset \sigma(\mathbb C)$ and $\sigma(\mathbb C)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathbb C$. Thus, it suffices to show that $\mathbb C \subset \mathbb G$)
2. Why does $\mathbb G = \sigma(\mathbb C)$ imply the conclusion?

Comment: What is the role of $\mathbb{M}$?

Comment: It is just a $\sigma$-algebra on $E$, it may be omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Take $\mathbb{D}=\mathbb{C}$. Therefore $\mathbb{C}\subset\mathbb{G}$.

**2.** By definition of $\mathbb{G}$: For all $B\in\sigma(\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{G}$ there is a countable familly $\mathbb{D}\subset\mathbb{C}$ such that $B\in\sigma(\mathbb{D})$.

Comment: Ah yes, how silly I am! I just made it so complicated.